# A rendering error occurred: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Tags: experience-editor, jss

Trying to add RouteType item (as provided in samples on creating a new JSS app).

[image]

Once I add in experience editor, it appears fine like below
[image]

But as soon as I click save, I got below error message. Anyone faced similar issue?

[image]